# Copy words from a file

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

I need to copy a text from a .text file into another .txt file. The only restriction i have is that if there are any repetition i'll put the word in the new file only one time. The only value that separate the words in the original file is the space. I'm thinking about copy the entire text into a string then check for repetitions but i don't know how to check and if is a good idea. Can you guys help me with some ideas?

Comment: make Binary-tree (or such like trie, map(or set))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The strategy

We need a data structure that can hold an unlimited number of words, lets call it *SET*.

This structure must have an operation to add a word in it, lets call it *SET::ADD*.
The return value of such an operation must indicate if the word as been added or if there was an error.

The peculiarity of the *SET* structure is that a word can be added only once, so there are two error values returned by *SET::ADD*: *GENERIC_ERROR* for an internal implementation error and *DUPLICATE* for the attempt to insert an already present word.

The *SET* structure also has an operation to initialize it (*SET::INIT*) and one to free it (*SET::FREE*).

We then read the words from the input file, one word at a time and we add each one to the *SET* structure.
If the insertion is successful we write such a word to the output file, otherwise we skip this step.

**Pseudo algorithm**

```
1. S = SET::INIT
2. FIN = OpenFile(input_file)
3. FOUT = OpenFile(output_file);
4. FOR EACH WORD IN FIN
4.1   IF SET::ADD(S, WORD) == SUCCESS THEN
4.1.1    WriteToFile(FOUT, WORD)
4.2   END IF
5. CloseFile(FIN);
6. CloseFile(FOUT);
7. SET::FREE(S);
```

## The tactic

The real hard work here is implementing the *SET* structure.
A data structures is defined by the operations that can be performed on it and by the pre and post conditions of this operations.

So in theory we only need to do this simple things when implementing *SET::ADD*: **search if the word is already present**, **add it**:

```
 1. FUNCTION SET::ADD(S, W)
 1.1   FOR EACH WORD IN S
 1.1.1   IF WORD == W THEN
 1.1.1.1   RETURN DUPLICATE
 1.1.2   END IF
 1.2   ADD W TO S
```

These two steps are heavily implementation dependent.
There are a number of implementations for a data structure with this requirements, for example a very naive implementation could use **a fixed size array of pointers**. This however has serious drawbacks.
A better implementation could be a **linked list**, this let us insert an unlimited number of words but require linear time for insertion and search!

So we enter the realm of time complexity.
I'll tell you by now that this structure can be implemented with amortized constant time.  But lets start from the beginning.

The next logical steps from the linked list are: use a **binary tree**, use and **hash table**.
Both can do an insertion and a search at the same time, i.e. both operations can be merged.
The first take **O**(*log n*) to insert and search, the second in **O**(*1*).
The first however being more structured let us not only do search but also do ordered search.  This features is not useful for this problem, so we should pick the hash table.

I picked the tree instead.  This is because binary tree let you practice with pointers and recursion better than hash table, being a **Well Founded Type** (when you will attend a Type Theory course you will thank me!).

If you are not familiar with binary trees, get it now! Ask Google or your teacher!

## The implementation

A node of our tree should contains

- The word it stores
- A link (i.e. pointer) to its left subtree
- A link (i.e. pointer) to its right subtree

The last two are straightforward, the first can be implemented as a pointer or as a fixed size in-structure array.
I chose the latter as it makes the node to require only one call to `malloc`, this is also supported by the fact that we have a maximum size for a word since we read it with `fscanf`.

Some notes to the code

- I have used pointers to pointer to implement `add_word`, this make the solution elegant but keep pencil and paper at hand!
- Also I (should) have made sure that no buffer overflow can happen by using `strncpy`, `snprintf` and dynamically making the `fscanf` format specifier with the right len. *This is good practice*-
- I have used an `assert` to check if the allocated size for the format specifier buffer is not large enough, this is because the right size can be computed by the programmer and once the code is compiled it stays fixed, so no need for heavy runtime checks.
- The format specifier used with `fscanf` is in the form *%s* where  is *MAX_WORD_SIZE*, so for example it turns out to be "%40s".
- I free the three from leafs to root using recursion for fun.

---

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


/* Values returned by add_word */
/* The word has been added to the tree      */  
#define AW_ADDED         0  
/* The word cannot be added as malloc failed*/          
#define AW_ERROR        -1  
/* The word is a duplicate                  */  
#define AW_DUPLICATE     1      

/* Maximum size of a word                   */
#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 40        


/* Structure of the binary tree node        */
typedef struct node
{
    struct node* left;              /* Ptr to left (less than) branch       */
    struct node* right;             /* Ptr to right (greater than) branch   */
    char word[MAX_WORD_SIZE+1];     /* Word stored in the node              */
} node;


/*
    Add a word to the tree identified by the root pointer.
    This function allocate all the memory itself, the root of a tree is a pointer to a node structure.

    root is a pointer to the root (a ptr to ptr since the root may be updated)
    word is the word to add
*/
int add_word(node** root, const char* word)
{
    int compare;

    /* Traverse the tree until you find a null pointer (beware, we work with ptr to ptr) */
    while (*root)
    {
        /* Compare the current node word with the given one */
        compare = strcmp(word, (*root)->word);

        /* They are equal? Easy, just return the appropriate value */
        if (!compare)
            return AW_DUPLICATE;

        /* Move to the left of right based on the sign of the comparison */
        root = compare < 0 ? &((*root)->left) : &((*root)->right);
    }

    /* We found a null ptr to update with a ptr to a new node */

    /* Allocate memory */
    if (!(*root = malloc(sizeof(node))))
        return AW_ERROR;

    /* Init the new node */
    (*root)->left = (*root)->right = 0;

    /* Copy the given word, up to MAX_WORD_SIZE byte*/
    strncpy((*root)->word, word, MAX_WORD_SIZE);

    /* Set a null terminator on the last byte in the case the word is exactly MAX_WORD_SIZE char*/
    (*root)->word[MAX_WORD_SIZE] = 0;

    return AW_ADDED;
}

/*
   Free the memory used by the tree
   Set the pointers to NULL.
   Use recursion for didactic purpose, an iterative solution would consume less resources as
   this is NOT tail recursion.
 */
void free_tree(node** root)
{
    if (*root)
    {
        /* Go to children nodes */
        free_tree(&((*root)->left));
        free_tree(&((*root)->right));

        /* Free current node */
        free(*root);
        *root = NULL;
    }

}

int main()
{
    /* Open the files */
    FILE* fin = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    FILE* fout = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    /* Check the descriptors */
    if (!fin)
        return printf("Cannot open input file\n"), 1;

    if (!fout)
        return printf("Cannot open output file\n"), 2;

    /* This is out tree */
    node* root = NULL;
    /* This is the buffer for reading word from fin*/
    char new_word[MAX_WORD_SIZE+1];
    /* This is the buffer for creating fscanf format specifier*/
    char format[32];

    /* Create the fscanf format specifier */
    int char_used = snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ds", MAX_WORD_SIZE);
    assert(char_used + 1 <= sizeof(format));

    /* Read the file until the end */
    while (!feof(fin))
    {
        /* Read a word and add it to the tree, if it is added, write it to new file */
        if (fscanf(fin, format, new_word) && add_word(&root, new_word) == AW_ADDED)
            fprintf(fout, "%s ", new_word);                             
    }

    /* Close and exit */
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    free_tree(&root);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try hashing the strings with MD5 or something similar, then storing them in a binary tree. Should have a reasonably low average time complexity. I'm not really sure how fast MD5 is though; there might be a better hash algorithm for small strings.

You could just store all the strings in an array and use strcmp on all of them every time you pick up a new string if you don't care about efficiency though.